# uwsgi serve larger static files

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have an uwsgi+nginx+django development setup and having a little issue with uwsgi serving larger static files, eg. the leaflet.js which is 120487 in size, resulting the following error:

```
SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /static/js/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js (ip 125.236.123.123) !!!
uwsgi_response_write_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 296]
```

here is the ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/%n.sock
master = true
processes = 5
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=abc.settings
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
pythonpath = /var/www/abc/abc
chdir = /var/www/abc/abc
chmod-socket = 666
uid = www-data
virtualenv = /var/www/abc
vacuum = true
procname-prefix-spaced = %n
cheaper = 1
plugins = python
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
sharedarea = 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, I had folder ownership problem in /var and I reset everything back to root and hence nginx was having wrong permission writing files in /var/lib/nginx

```
chmod -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx
```

Comment: Care to add a little explanation?